# Determine the sign of an integral without evaluating it

Tags: real-analysis

This is from a real analysis module. I'm supposed to determine whether this integral is positive or negative without evaluating it. I have no idea how. Obviously $xcos(x)$ is positive over $(0,\frac\pi2)$ and negative over $(\frac\pi2,\pi)$, so whichever partial integral is larger obviously determines the sign of the full integral, but how can I do that without evaluating the partial integrals? Or is there a trick to proving this that I'm unaware of?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You know by symmetry the integral would be 0 if the integrand was $\cos(x)$. What is the sign of $\cos(x)$ when the $x$ affects the magnitude the most?

You are correct in splitting it into partial integrals, but which one logically should be larger? When is $x$ larger?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you know that $$\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos x \ dx = - \int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} \cos x \ dx$$

Now toss in an $x$ into each integral. How does the *value of $x$ in each interval* affect each integral above? Is there still equality?